# CodecNotFoundException при запросе в cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

Что, где и как я должен что то зарегестрировать как кодек для пользовательского типа

определил тип

```
@UDT(name = "bucket", keyspace = "us")
public class BucketType {

  @Field(name = "event_time")
  private Date eventTime;

  @Field(name = "product_id")
  private String productId;
  //setters and getters
}
```

структура таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.shops (       
    user_id stext,              
    buckets list<frozen <bucket>>   
PRIMARY KEY (user_id));
```

Зависимости

```
    compile group: 'com.datastax.cassandra', name: 'cassandra-driver-mapping', version: '3.5.0'
    compile group: 'com.datastax.cassandra', name: 'cassandra-driver-core', version: '3.5.0'
```

Делаю запрос в cassandra

```
Session session = cluster.connect();
ResultSet resultSet = session.execute("select * from keyspace.shops;");
  resultSet.forEach(row -> {
  List<BucketType> list1 = row.getList(1, BucketType.class);
  }
```

Пробовал разные методы get, getValue, и индексы разные 
Выдает ошибку

```
   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [ups.cart_add <-> com.test.entity.type.BucketType]
at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.notFound(CodecRegistry.java:741) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.5.0.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:588) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.5.0.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.findCodec(CodecRegistry.java:558) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.5.0.jar:na]
```

Comment: попробуйте `row.getList("buckets", BucketType.class)`

Comment: Пробовал,  такая же ошибка

Comment: а если попробовать `row.getList("buckets", TypeToken.of(BucketType.class)) `

Comment: Точно такая же ошибка

Comment: может быть вы не к тому keyspace подключайтесь? попробуйте указать `cluster.connect("ups")`.

Comment: данные в row есть, через cluster.connect("us") Такая же ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании деклараций, лучше [использовать Mapper API](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/object_mapper/using/), а не стандартные функции...

Но можно работать и с результатом полученным через них, только надо добавить маппинг для самой таблицы `shop` (пусть это будет класс `Shop`, и враппер:

```
Mapper<Shop> mapper = manager.mapper(Shop.class);
ResultSet resultSet = session.execute("select * from keyspace.shops;");
Result<Shop> shops = mapper.map(resultSet);
...
```

Соответвтвующая [документация](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/object_mapper/using/#manual-mapping)...

Или можно [сделать доступ через Accessors](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/object_mapper/using/#accessors) (не знаю как перевести)...